# ANTLR: Match unescaped characters?

Tags: antlr

I've got a rule like,

```
charGroup
    : '[' .+ ']';
```

But I'm guessing that'll match something like `[abc\]`. Assuming I want it to match only unescaped `]`s, how do I do that? In a regular expression I'd use a negative look-behind.

**Edit:** I'd also like it to be ungreedy/lazy if possible. So as to match only `[a]` in `[a][b]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably wanted to do something like:

```
charGroup
  :  '[' ('\\' . | ~('\\' | ']'))+ ']'
  ;
```

where `~('\\' | ']')` matches a single character other than `\` and `]`. Note that you can only negate single characters! There's no such thing as `~('ab')`. Another mistake often made is that negating inside parser rules does not negate a character, but a token instead. An example might be in order:

```
foo : ~(A | D);

A : 'a';
B : 'b';
C : 'c';
D : ~A;
```

Now parser rule `foo` matches either token `B` or token `C` (so only the characters `'b'` and `'c'`) while lexer rule `D` matches any character other than `'a'`.

Comment: That looks like it should work. Is there no such thing as zero-width assertions though? Would be nice if I could factor out an unescaped `]` for re-use. Also, thanks for the tips, I'll try to keep those in mind.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean by *"factor out an unescaped ] for re-use"* (it's early here! :))...

Comment: I mean, would it be possible to define a rule `RBracket : ']'` such that it matches only an unescaped `]`. Then I can define charGroup simply as `charGroup: LBracket .+ RBracket`, and it would be useful in a few other places in my grammar as well. Technically, the left bracket should be unescaped too.

Comment: Perhaps using those predicates you linked me to before? Not sure if those can be negated though.

Comment: @Ralph, yes, that is possible, but I would hesitate going down that route. There shouldn't be too much "intelligence" in the lexer IMO. I think it's better to define a rule above `RBracket`, say `EscSeq`, that matches a backslash followed by some other character. Because it's placed above `RBracket`, there won't ever be a backslash before a `]`: lexer rules are matched from top to bottom in your `.g` grammar file.
Also consider the string `\\\]` where there is a backslash before the bracket, but it's not escaping the bracket but the backslash before it.

Comment: @Bart: You're right! I think I've been writing a lot of incorrect regular expressions :( Forgot about the escaped slash.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd use a negative look-behind

Isn't that unnecessarily complex? How about:

```
charGroup
    : '[' ('\\]' | .)+ ']';
```

Comment: Sneaky... put the `\\]` in there so it eats it before it can match the `]`. Is the `+` operator greedy in ANTLR? If I have something like `[a][b]` will the charGroup be the whole thing, or just `[a]`? Also, if possible, I'd still like to use some sort of negation, then I can toss it into a separate rule, `RBRACKET`, which I could use in other places as well.

Comment: @Ralph, the `+` and `*` are greedy in ANTLR except when preceded by a `.` (some people might argue about this, but they're wrong! It's in the ANTLR reference from Terence Parr). So `.*` and `.+` are non-greedy, all other `+`'s and `*`'s *are* greedy.

Comment: @Bart: Thanks. That's a curious decision... seems a bit inconsistent, but I guess I can see how that would be useful in practice.

Comment: @Ralph, yeah I can imagine you find it curious. Terence explains his motivations behind this decision in [The Definitive ANTLR reference](http://pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr/the-definitive-antlr-reference), Ch 4, Extended BNF Subrules, page 86.

Comment: @Bart: I kind of just skimmed through that section :) I guess I'll have to go through it in more detail. Thanks (again)!

Comment: @jpalecek: This looks like the simpler of the 2 solutions, and it's easier to understand, so I'll accept it. They both appear to be semantically equivalent.

Comment: @Ralph, I would urge against using `.` in there. Since you don't want to match a single `]` and a backslash, I'd use `~('\\' | ']')` instead. And since you want to match short-hand character classes like `\w`, `\d` etc. and not just `\\[`, I'd also opt to use either `\\.` or define a separate lexer rule called `EscapeSequence` that captures all those escaped chars.

Comment: @Ralph, also, this suggestion will not properly parse input like: `[\\\]]`. This will be interpreted as: `[`, 'single-backslash', 'single-backslash+close-bracket' and `]`, which is wrong. 
It should be: `[`, 'escaped-backslash', `]` and `]` instead.

Comment: @Bart: The escape sequences are going to be a little more complicated than that. `\uXXXX` for example is more than just a slash followed by a single char. I have these in a separate lexer rule already....maybe this problem is a complete non-issue because once I substitute in my EscapeSequence rule, all the slashes should be eaten before it gets to the `]`.